# How to make reusable AlertDialog?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

Flutter example for `AlertDialog` is:

```
Future<void> neverSatisfied() async {
  return showDialog<void>(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Rewind and remember'),
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ListBody(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('You will never be satisfied.'),
              Text('You\’re like me. I’m never satisfied.'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Regret'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  );
}
```

But I want make this reusable so I can call it and pass in custom text for example:

```
await neverSatisfied(context, text: text);
```

How can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can create an alert dialog in separate class like below and can use that any where you want:

> Note: pass context with "GlobalKey()" like used in
>   below class otherwise alert dialog will not display and give you error
>   such as "The specific widget that could not find a
>   MaterialLocalizations ancestor was"

Declare separate Utility class that will help to display dialog:

> Utility

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Utility{

  static Utility utility = null;

  static Utility getInstance(){
    if(utility == null){
      utility = Utility();
    }
    return utility;
  }

  showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, String alertTitle, String alertMessage){
    // set up the buttons
    Widget cancelButton = FlatButton(
      child: Text("Cancel"),
      onPressed:  () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
    Widget continueButton = FlatButton(
      child: Text("Continue"),
      onPressed:  () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );

    // set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text(alertTitle),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ListBody(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(alertMessage)
          ],
        ),
      ),
      actions: [
        cancelButton,
        continueButton,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );

  }

}
```

Use that dialog in main.dart as below:

> Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_demo_app/Utility.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('AlertDialog')),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Get AlertDialog 1'),
              onPressed: () {
                Utility.getInstance().showAlertDialog(navigatorKey.currentState.overlay.context, 'Rewind and remember', 'You will never be satisfied.');
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Get AlertDialog 2'),
              onPressed: () {
                Utility.getInstance().showAlertDialog(navigatorKey.currentState.overlay.context, 'RememberRewinded', 'You\’re like me. I’m never satisfied.');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I understand this method but I not like the way it pass String to AlertDialog. It not clear in main.dart what this is refer to when you just look at it for first time. In you example I want specify: `Utility.getInstance().showAlertDialog(navigatorKey.currentState.overlay.context, alertTitle: 'RememberRewinded', alertMessage: 'You\’re like me. I’m never satisfied.');`

Comment: you can pass custom text here but let me know what you want then i'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks! My issue is it is not very clean in code to have: `await neverSatisfied(context, 'Rewind and remember', 'You will never be satisfied.');`. It is not clear what the 2 string will do in alertdialog. It more clear to have `await neverSatisfied(context, title: 'Rewind and remember', body: 'You will never be satisfied.');`. So when someone read code can see very quick what String is title and what is body so can edit easy.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I created a reusable custom dialog...I made a new dart file and made a stateless widget called CustomAlert which takes an onPress and a message as parameter.

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomAlert extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? message;
  final onPress;

  CustomAlert({this.message, this.onPress});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 48.0),
          child: AlertDialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40, top: 20),
            actionsPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 30),
            actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            actions: [
              ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text(
                    "RETRY",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 12,
                        letterSpacing: 7,
                        wordSpacing: 5,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all(4),
                    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.only(
                        right: 30, left: 30, top: 10, bottom: 10)),
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
                    textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                      const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 10,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: onPress),
            ],
            content: Text(message!,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.black)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After this, I just called it on another file using showDialog.

```
  showDialog(
  context: this.context,
  builder: (ctx) => CustomAlert(
        message:
            "Hello there",
        onPress: () {
          Navigator.pop(this.context);
        },
      ));
```

Answer (score 0):

to refer alertTitle and alertMessage, add { } in showAlertDialog fields

example:

> Utility

```
showAlertDialog(
      {BuildContext context, String alertTitle, String alertMessage}).....
```

and call:

> Main.dart

```
AlertWidget.getInstance().showAlertDialog(context: context, alertTitle: 'alert', alertMessage: "message",
      );
```